# Slide menu collapse with icons, responsive with AngularJS Bootstrap3

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Do you know where I can find a left side menu, with push content and a responsive design, which when collapse show icons of the menus, and when uncollapse show the entire menus.

exemple :

> **Image 1 : mouse is out of the menu**

[image]

> **Image 2 : mouse is over of the menu**

[image]

This menu is mine, but when I zoom on my page the menu take all the page and the center content is placed under the menu.

Comment: http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0RR5C65 this it what I'm looking for, but free

Comment: check demo ..  ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Check This `Live Demo`..

**Demo :** https://codepen.io/kumarrishikesh12/pen/awEBmN

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300);
.fa-2x {
font-size: 2em;
}
.fa {
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
width: 60px;
height: 36px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:20px;
}


.main-menu:hover,nav.main-menu.expanded {
width:250px;
overflow:visible;
}

.main-menu {
background:darkblue;
border-right:1px solid #e5e5e5;
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
height:100%;
left:0;
width:60px;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
transition:width .05s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
z-index:1000;
}

.main-menu>ul {
margin:7px 0;
}

.main-menu li {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:250px;
}

.main-menu li>a {
position:relative;
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
color:#999;
 font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
transition:all .1s linear;
  
}

.main-menu .nav-icon {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
width:60px;
height:36px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size:18px;
}

.main-menu .nav-text {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:190px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.main-menu>ul.logout {
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover {
overflow-y:hidden;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
overflow-y:auto;
overflow:visible;
}

a:hover,a:focus {
text-decoration:none;
}

nav {
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
-o-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
}

nav ul,nav li {
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.main-menu li:hover>a,nav.main-menu li.active>a,.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.dropdown-menu>.active>a,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
color:#fff;
background-color:#5fa2db;
}
.area {
float: left;
background: #e2e2e2;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Titillium WebLight'), local('TitilliumWeb-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v2/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr24bNCNEoFTpS2BTjF6FB5E.woff) format('woff');
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
 
  </head>
  <body><div class="area"></div><nav class="main-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Dashboard
                        </span>
                    </a>
                  
                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            UI Components
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    
                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Forms
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    
                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Pages
                        </span>
                    </a>
                   
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Graphs and Statistics
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-font fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Typography and Icons
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Tables
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Maps
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Documentation
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="logout">
                <li>
                   <a href="#">
                         <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Logout
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>  
            </ul>
        </nav>
  </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: yeah it seems to be what I need. And how cann add an "hamburger" button with small resolution ? in the link  
wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0RR5C65 if you zoom the menu is hidden and a button appear at top right

Comment: use bootstrap `Menu-hamburger` .. for this simple and  this div called inside that.

Comment: :) :) .. any time .. happy to help

Comment: I don't manage to push content to the right while the menu is expanded :/ the content next to my menu is going down the menu instead of resizing

Comment: okzz no problem can you please upload the update code.. which you add..  or update in my codepen send me link back ..